# Android animate text when calling setText()

Tags: android, android-animation, textview, android-textattributes

I want to animated text to fade in and out when changing I am extending `TextSwitcher` in order to define this once since I have many `TextSwitcher` objects.

However I keep on getting a Null pointer "java.lang.NullPointerException
android.widget.TextSwitcher.setText(TextSwitcher.java:80) when doing this :

```
homeTeamTextView.setText("Text");
```

I decided to extend the TextSwitcher class like this:

```
public class MyTextSwitcher extends TextSwitcher{

public MyTextSwitcher(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    setInAnimation(context,R.anim.fade_in);
    setOutAnimation(context,R.anim.fade_out);
}}
```

Activity

```
private MyTextSwitcher homeTeamTextView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    homeTeamTextView = (MyTextSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.hometeam);
    awayScoreTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.awayteamscore);
    homeScoreTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hometeamscore);
    gameStatusTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gamestatus);
    gameClockTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gameclock);
    gameStartTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gamestart);
    gameClockSectionTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gameclocksection);

    LoadDataAsyncTask loadDataTask = new LoadDataAsyncTask();
    loadDataTask.execute();
}
```

Layout:

```
  <com.MyTextSwitcher
        android:id="@+id/hometeam"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />
```

Comment: where have you kept your animation files fade in and fade out??

Comment: I think problem is here setInAnimation(context,R.anim.fade_in);
    setOutAnimation(context,R.anim.fade_out); Instead write android.R.anim.fade_in,android.R.fade_out as as second parameters

Answer (score 0):

It looks that TextSwitcher is common ViewSwitcher which can contain only TextViews. When you call setText() it try to get next view. You can find it in source: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/TextSwitcher.java, but it's null. I think you must add textView inside your TextSwitcher (or even two textView to properly working animation).